What is the mean of random effects?
Say, I have a mixed model: y = x + y + x:y + (1 + x * y | participant)
What would be the mean of the random effects? Do they fluctuate around 0 or the fixed effects?

In mixed model terminology, a random effect is typically a normally distributed effect with mean zero and some unknown variance to be estimated:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y} &= \mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{\upsilon} + \mathbf{\epsilon} \\ \\
\mathbf{\upsilon} &\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{0}, \Sigma_\upsilon \right) \\ \\\mathbf{\epsilon} &\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
If the mean were non-zero, you would have a constant deviation from the model, which should already captured by the intercept and fixed effect(s).

$\upsilon$ should be multivariate normal. $\mathcal{N} (\vec 0, \Sigma_\upsilon)$,as the different random coefficients within one group are usually assumed to be correlated and have different variance.

Ah, good point, thanks! I updated the answer
